# what is dark magic behind meta.Vectors?

Tags: simd, zig

After implementing some vector algebra based on generic algorithms and iterators, I decided to run some benchmarks. The idea was to compare custom vectors' with `meta.Vector`s' performance (doing addition and scaling).

When vectors' size was set to 10, custom vectors slightly outperformed `meta.Vector`s. When vectors' size was set to 100, `meta.Vector`s slightly outperformed custom vectors. When vectors' size was set to 1000, custom vectors performed addition twice as slowly as `meta.Vector`s and scaling -- slightly more slowly than `meta.Vector`s (using `@splat`).

Funniest thing is compilation times -- those grew with vectors' size growth (didn't measure, can't tell if compilation time was linear in vectors' size). When vectors' size was set to 10_000, I eventually (after a long wait) received `shell returned 137` error message (during compilation); after I've commented out any mention of `meta.Vector`, code compiled just fine.

So my question is what kind of (compiler?) dark magic makes 1000-sized `meta.Vector`s work so fast and can I use it to make my code faster?

P. S.: benchmarks were run with -O ReleaseFast, all variables were marked `var`

P. P. S.: in debug mode code with 10_000-sized `meta.Vector`s eventually compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK all it does is explicitly leverage LLVM's SIMD support.

https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.8.0/#Vectors